# How to add a short wav music clip into a Mathematica animation

Tags: animation, sound

I have the following Mathematica animation:

```
Animate[Plot[k*x^2, {x, -2, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-10, 10}}], {k, -2, 2, 0.1}]
```

I also have a sound file in the same Mathematica file, which is A VERY SHORT music clip, in "wav" format.  The clip is about 32 seconds long.  Now I want to integrate this sound file into the above animation:

The following command will do the job, but it will make the animation WAY TOO sluggish, and almost useless:

```
Animate[Plot[k*x^2, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-10, 10}}, 
  Epilog -> {EmitSound[snd]}], {k, -2, 2, 0.1}]
```

Could you please suugest a better way of doing it?  Thank you very much!

Comment: How long is the .wav file? Do you need it to play continuously during animation or only at the beginning/end ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one way to control the sound emission. Import a short .WAV file:

```
sound = Import[ "ExampleData/rule30.wav" ]
```

[image]

Now make sound **only** when your animation control reaches some value - **k=0** or **k=1** in this case:

```
Animate[If[k == 0 || k == 1, EmitSound[sound]];
 Plot[k*x^2, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-10, 10}}],
 {k, -2, 2, 0.1, AnimationRate -> 1, AnimationRunning -> False}]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Mr. Vitaliy Kaurov, Thank you very much for your help. It works. I still have a question related to your answer. I will ask you later. I was slightly confused about the use of semicolon (;) after the EmitSound[sound]] command, and all that is included within the Animate command. I have never used such within an Animate command. I will try to understand it myself - if not perhaps I can ask you again. Still, thank you so much! Tim –

Comment: PS:  You had asked how long is the wav file.  Mine was about 32 seconds long.  Using your method, it plays again and again without a problem.  A second question is that can I cut off the music for certain values of k, and again restart it when k equals the previous values?  I was just wondering.  What is the Mathematica command to make a sound silent, in other words?  Thanks in advance

Comment: @Tim , I will ponder about your question a bit. Meanwhile it maybe worth posting it as a separate question. Because it is a good question and also maybe someone already knows the answer.